# php cURL script run twice

Tags: php, curl

I have a tragedic issue, with my curl, i want to post one time and my action is executed twice.

I don't have two curl_exec() or is not a html output problem, and i have aldready search to my best friend Google, and to other post on stackoverflow.
My request is send successfully, but the last problem is that ...

My config

```
      CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false,      
      CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,      
      CURLOPT_FAILONERROR    => true,      
      CURLOPT_POST           => true,       
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $postFields, 
      CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
      CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS      =>  CURLPROTO_HTTP,
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'

$CURL=curl_init();

if(empty($CURL)){die("ERREUR");}
       curl_setopt_array($CURL,$options);

      curl_exec($CURL);

        curl_close($CURL);  

      $content = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();

      if(curl_errno($CURL)){
            echo "ERREUR curl_exec : ".curl_error($CURL); 
      }

      ob_end_flush();


echo $content;
```

Have you any idea to resolve that, thanks.

Comment: Do you call this via Ajax? Could be your javaScript that is the problem. Provide a little more code

Comment: No, i call the file directly from my browser !

Comment: Could have something to do with `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` but it's not enough code to make conclusion

Comment: Do you ever have an `ob_start()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your curl only executes once but outputs twice.
The first one comes from `curl_exec($CURL)`, because CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is false,

> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
>   [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

The second one is obviously from `echo $content;`